# Ayuda con un algoritmo que convierte números a palabras en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy en un proyecto de hacer una librería en *JavaScript*.

https://github.com/gpincheiraa/number2words

Se trata de convertir números a palabras.

Se han hecho *suite test* y tengo problemas con números mayores a mil billones, no toma los tres últimos números.

[Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/2fn445g8/)

**number**: *Input* dado.

**chunk_index**: Índice del chunk analizado.

**total_chunks**: Total de los *chunks* a analizar. Se pasa como argumento para evitar recalcular este valor en las futuras iteraciones.

**converted_text**: Texto parcial calculado.

**flag**: Advierte que el próximo postfijo será **mil** para aplicarlo en números mayores a **1 millón**.

Código:

```
function convert(number, chunk_index, total_chunks, converted_text, flag){
    //**********      VARIABLES INICIALES  ********************************
    var chunk_regex = /\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})*$)/g, 
        text = converted_text || '',
        chunk,
        chunk_number,
        chunk_block;
    //***********     VALIDACIÓN Y SANITIZACIÓN DE FORMATO *******************

    number += '';
    //**********       INICIALIZACIONES  **********************
    total_chunks = total_chunks || Math.ceil(number.length/3);
    chunk_index = chunk_index || 0;
    //Tomamos el match correspondiente al índice que la función recursiva está analizando. 
    //Aprovechamos de aplicar el operador ++. Este operador es un shortcut para aplicar la operación ++ en la línea siguiente.

    chunk = (number).match(chunk_regex)[chunk_index++];
    chunk_number = parseInt(chunk, 10);
    //Calculamos el bloque correspondiente al exponente del número.
    chunk_block = total_chunks - chunk_index;
    //************   LÓGICA DE CONVERSIÓN **********************
    //Le aplicamos al chunk analizado las reglas ortográficas
    if(!(chunk_block > 0 && chunk_number === 0) && !(chunk_block % 2 !== 0 && chunk_number === 1)){
      text+=' <br> A: ' + chunk + ' ' + chunk_index + ' ' + total_chunks + ' ' + chunk_block + ' \n';
      console.log('A: ' + chunk, chunk_index, total_chunks, chunk_block + ' \n')
      //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    }
    //Definimos si es necesario agregar postfijo al texto resultante que se aplicaron las reglas.
    if(chunk_block > 0 || flag === 1){
      text+=' <br> B: ' + chunk_block + ' ' + chunk_number + ' ' + chunk_index + ' ' + flag + ' \n';
      console.log('B: ' + chunk_block, chunk_number, chunk_index,flag + ' \n')
      //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
      flag = 0;
      //Si el siguiente número postfijo es "mil", entra esta y en la proxima iteración de la recursión, este tendrá el postfijo plural
      //(inclusive si es 0)
      if(chunk_block > 3 && chunk_block * 3 % 3 === 0 && chunk_block * 3 % 2 !== 0 && chunk_number > 0){
        flag = true;
      }
    }
    //************   RECURSIVIDAD **********************
    //Consultamos si la función recursiva debe terminar de invocarse
    if(chunk_index === total_chunks){
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    }
    else{
      return convert(number, chunk_index, total_chunks, text, flag);
    }
}

convert(123456789123456789);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema reside en que en Javascript el número entero más grande que se puede representar con el tipo primitivo **Number** es 9007199254740991, que puedes consultarlo en la constante `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. Por lo que si le das un valor más grande no puede guardarlo en memoria y lo trunca.

Como solución te aconsejo tomar el input como una cadena de texto, y si su longitud es mayor 16 entonces partirla y tratar los trozos por separado.

Referencias: [ECMA Section 8.5 - Numbers](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5) y [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: Excelente respuesta! Gracias por enseñar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, leeré las referencias, un gran aporte!